# Request to reopen question 461022

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions, reopen-request

I've made drastic changes to this closed question [How does the CPU and GPU interact in displaying computer graphics?](https://superuser.com/questions/461022/how-does-the-cpu-and-gpu-interact-in-displaying-computer-graphics). Since it was a quite popular one with more than 300 views in just a couple of hours I'd really like to reopen it instead of posing a new question.

Comment: "*I'd really like to reopen it instead of posing a new question.*" You should **always** try to reopen before posting a new question. Well done! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done; I've reopened the question

Answer (score 0):

**For reopening questions** do the following

1. Flag the question
2. Choose moderator attention and other optional buttons on the popup window
3. State the reason why it need to be reopened in others box

As the users usually post their request to reopen their questions and it lead to increase in spam if they goon requesting their questions.

Follow the simple procedure to bring moderator attention to reopen the question, the moderators will consider and reply it as soon as possible